# Include 0 values into group by in sql

Tags: sql, db2

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM castle c, resource r
WHERE db2gse.ST_Contains(r.geom, c.geom) = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

It will give me the castles and their number of resources, if the number of resources is 1 or higher. Now I also want the castles that have no resources.

A castle has an id and a geometry, a resource has an id and a geometry.

So I want this query to give me all the castles and their number of resources, even if the number of resources is 0. You can see if a castle has a certain resource by checking of the castle's location is inside the resource, by checking if the geometry of the resource contains the geometry of the castle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explicit `join` syntax, so you can use a `left join`:

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(r.<col>) AS num
FROM castle c LEFT JOIN
     resource r
     ON db2gse.ST_Contains(r.geom, c.geom) = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

A simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

EDIT:

You need a column in the `resource` table for the count, but `geom` may not work (depending on its type).  If you don't have one, then phrase the query like this:

```
select c.id,
       (select count(*)
        from resource r
        where db2gse.ST_Contains(r.geom, c.geom) = 1
       ) as num
from castle c;
```

Comment: Running your query gives me an error: SQL0245N  The invocation of routine "COUNT" is ambiguous. The argument in
position "1" does not have a best fit.  SQLSTATE=428F5

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden . . . Is there another column in the `resource` table that you can use?